# How to float these without them moving when re-sizing?

Tags: html, css

I want my website to be all resolution friendly so everything is centered and when I shrink the window it all moves to the left and stops. However, my news feed drops below the poll when I shrink the window.

Heres the css code:

```
#poll {
float: left;
margin: 0px 20px;
}

#newsfeed {
float: right;
margin: 0px 20px;
}

 <div id="poll">
 <form method="post" action="http://poll.pollcode.com/t78ar8"><table border=0 width="244" bgcolor="EEEEEE" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0"><tr><td colspan="2" height="10"><font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><b>What game site do you visit most?</b></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" id="t78ar8answer1"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer1">Ign</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" id="t78ar8answer2"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer2">GameSpot</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" id="t78ar8answer3"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer3">GameFAQs</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" id="t78ar8answer4"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer4">GamerZone</label></font></td></tr><tr><td width="5"><input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" id="t78ar8answer5"></td><td>&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma" size="2" color="000000"><label for="t78ar8answer5">Mmohut</label></font></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" height="10"><center><input type="submit" value=" Vote ">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="view" value=" View "></center></td></tr></a>&nbsp;</font></td></tr></table></form>

    </div>
    <div id="newsfeed">
    <!-- start sw-rss-feed code --> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    <!-- 
    rssfeed_url = new Array();   
    rssfeed_url[0]="http://news.yahoo.com/rss/gaming";
    rssfeed_frame_width="500"; 
    rssfeed_frame_height="720"; 
    rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
    rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
    rssfeed_scroll_bar="on"; 
    rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
    rssfeed_font_size="14"; 
    rssfeed_font_face=""; 
    rssfeed_border="on";
    rssfeed_css_url="http://udel.edu/~ssell/newsfeed.css";
    rssfeed_title="on"; 
    rssfeed_title_name=""; 
    rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
    rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
    rssfeed_title_bgimage="http://"; 
    rssfeed_footer="off"; 
    rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
    rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
    rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
    rssfeed_footer_bgimage="http://"; 
    rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
    rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
    rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
    rssfeed_item_bgimage="http://"; 
    rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
    rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
    rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
    rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
    rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
    rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
    rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
    rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
    rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
    rssfeed_cache = "7872565d53aadc6c14b4ab1bb3f79bdb"; 
    //--> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rss-feed.js"></script> 
    <!-- end sw-rss-feed code -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide the html.  A http://jsfiddle.net would also be good or a link to the project in question.

Comment: @Jrod Thanks for the advice. Why did my question get voted down though?

Comment: Most likely because it was lacking the html but I can't say for certain as I was not the one who down-voted.  Take a read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and you won't have any problems in the future.

Comment: I just assumed you did because you were the first comment sorry. Plus I didn't think the html was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution if you don't want to use responsive design or similar switches: 
Try wrapping the containers "#poll" and "#newsfeed" with another container (#wrapper) with following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
min-width:500px; /* 500px = max. sum of box model width values of #poll and #newsfeed" */
width: auto !important; /* IE>=7 */
width: 500px; /* IE<7 */
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that? I don't understand what responsive design or similar switches are.

Comment: You need a wrap with a specified fixed width around your block elements if you have must multiple containers which are not allowed to break if the viewport is resized. IE needs a little help for this.

By "responsive design or similar switches" i meant code which divers because rendered differently in clients by using client-side javascript, conditional comments or CSS media queries.

Comment: I got it after changing one thing but it was based off your answer so i'll give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Giving your container div a min-width and a max-width might resolve that problem.
Make sure your poll & newsfeed width combined with your margin don't exceed the min-width of your container.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="poll"> </div>
 <div id="newsfeed"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
max-width:1240px;
min-width:600px;
}
#poll {
float:right;
max-width:620px
min-width:280px;
margin:0 20px;
}
#newsfeed {
float:left;
max-width:620px;
min-width:280px;
margin:0 20px;
}
```

Comment: On lower resolutions the news feed still goes below the poll.